# Комп не правильно печатает с клавиатуры

Tags: железо

Всем привет! Такая проблема, я нажимаю на кнопку на клавиатуре, у меня может 2 символа напечататься, может 3, а может вообще не напечататься. Я уже и порты менял, иклавиатуру менял на новую, и залипание клавиш включал/выключал, даже ОС переустанавливал, ничего не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: скорее всего, проблема связанна с материнкой, попробуйте отнести в сервисный центр.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А без сервисного центра никак?